# how to create a multiply file dialog

Tags: jquery

what I'm trying to do is to allow uploading multiply files. each time use choose file i want to print it's name and add "remove" button next to it.

I want that browser dialog will open when user click on the plus icon (and not by clicking on the input field):

```
<button class="btn btn-default add" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

so far my plus button just add new file field and user need to click "browser".

https://jsfiddle.net/divspace/pwepeez1/

i want that plus button will open the file dialog. remember that it's for  multiply file uploaded....

This is what the HTML will look like:

```
<form id="form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="file">Upload Image</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input id="file" class="form-control" type="file" name="file[]" accept="image/*">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button class="btn btn-default add" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- START FILE UPLOAD TEMPLATE -->
    <div id="upload-template" class="form-group hide">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
            <input id="file" class="form-control" type="file" name="file[]" accept="image/*">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button class="btn btn-default remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END FILE UPLOAD TEMPLATE -->
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#form')
.on('click', '.add', function () {
    var $template = $('#upload-template');
    var $clone    = $template.clone().removeClass('hide').removeAttr('id').insertBefore($template);

    $clone.find('[name="file[]"]');
}).on('click', '.remove', function () {
    var $row = $(this).closest('.form-group');

    $row.find('[name="file[]"]');

    $row.remove();
});
```

Comment: For multiple files uploading, You may use attribute `multiple`.

Comment: thanks! what about my topic?

Comment: So you are going to press the button -> open dialog -> choose the files -> save them ?

Comment: I need to assign each chosen file to input field, no?